# New lines and tabs in json_decode() (PHP 7)

Tags: php, json, php-7

My code using `json_decode()` worked correctly with PHP 5.6. After migration to PHP 7.0, `json_decode()` returns NULL and `json_last_error()` tells me that my error is:

> Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded

After debugging, I found out that my problem are both tabs and new line characters in string values. If I remove them both, it works. If I leave **either** new lines **or** tabs, the error occurs.

Is `json_decode()` behavior changed in PHP 7? I would like to keep tabs and new lines in my .json files for better readability. The code works if I replace tabs to \t and new lines to \n.

How can I keep new lines and tabs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Due to a software licensing issue, the old `json` module was replaced with the `jsond` module. You can see the discussion of this change and the attached pull request [here](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/jsond). Now, there's not much information about the changes or about workarounds for things, but I can see that all control characters inside strings (`[\0x00-\0x1F]`) trigger an error. Unfortunately for you, it seems that this behavior is correct per the [JSON Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf):

> Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any token. The whitespace characters are: character tabulation (U+0009), line feed (U+000A), carriage return (U+000D), and space (U+0020). Whitespace is not allowed within any token, except that space is allowed in strings.

So, in other words, literal tabs are not allowed inside JSON strings at all; they must be `\t` or `\u0009`. So, the JSON you're consuming is in direct violation of the standard. Ideally, you should get your JSON source to return standards-compliant JSON. If that won't work, you'll have to pre-process the JSON and convert tabs inside strings to `\t`.

Comment: Amazing job, guys. Thanks a lot for enlightening me.

Answer (score 10):

I had same problem with new lines and i cant modify the string that i received. I needed to work with it and my trick was to detect the new lines and rewrite it again, 'literaly'!:

Before:

```
echo json_decode($json); // error JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR
```

After:

```
$json = str_replace("\r\n", '\r\n', $json); // single quotes do the trick
echo json_decode($json); // works!
```

Comment: I was thinking the way you thought, since you did the experiment already I got the necessary confidence. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you sir, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: its better `str_replace(["\r\n","\t"], ['\r\n','\t'],$json)`

Answer (score 4):

Tabs and newline characters, unencoded, are not allowed in strings in JSON according to [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7). Therefore, whatever program you used to encode has encoded a non-standard form of JSON. Unfortunately, [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)'s only option,  `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`, doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that with PHP 7, they decided to be more strict with JSON standards? If so, it's good in my opinion. Do you think I should sacrifice readability for following JSON standards? And, lastly, any reason why JSON doesn't support new lines and tabs as seen in text editors?

Comment: @Robo Robok: You can still use tabs and newline characters in a JSON document, but they can't appear in strings themselves without encoding them.

Comment: Yes, they've made it more standards-compliant, and yes, you should absolutely sacrifice the readability in order to use compliant JSON :)

Comment: Thank you for amazing answer. I will choose Will's answer because it contains more details. I hope you don't mind it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
$str = bin2hex('Text with special character /\"\'\b\f\t\r\n.'); // Convert binary data into hexadecimal representation
$arr = array("Some text", "Some text 2", $str);
$Json = json_encode($arr); // Now we are ready to send the json data
```

Here we will retrieve the json data

```
$arr_2 = json_decode($Json, true);
echo $arr_2[0];
echo $arr_2[1];
echo hex2bin($arr_2[2]);//Decodes a hexadecimally encoded binary string
```